# Is there any linux command to get host name from ip?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I want to get host name from ip. I  know a few command who does the work like host, nslookup and dig but they are not completely reliable. In many of the cases they fail to give the host name. So, is there any  command who can always give me the host name.

For ex: If I check "host stackoverflow.com" then it gives me a list of five different ip addresses. But when I check "host ip_address (each of the five different ip addresses)" than it's not able to find the host name.

Answer (score 1):

DNS has a **forward** and **reverse** zones and what are you going to get by requesting a domain name for an IP-address depends on reverse DNS-zone configuration of that domain name, that's not an application malfunction or something - it's just asking DNS-servers. So no, there's no such command that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting IP to hostname resolution, this means that the reverse lookup is either not allowed or not configured properly at the dns server (you are pointing to). In other words, PTR record does not exist, or you are not allowed access to it.

All the dns commands use the same or similar methods and underlying system calls to get the name; they search for the PTR record.

Without going into too much detail. If this is something you really want to do, you can look at other options like looking at the reconnaissance tools in Kali.